# Silent printing using PrintNode JS API

Tags: javascript, printing, silent

I am trying to use `PrintNode-JS` to silently print from within a browser using javascript and `PrintNode` remote printing service. But I am not able to do it properly. So I require some proper javascript code. I am trying following code:
https://www.printnode.com/

```
<script type='text/javascript'>

    var API_KEY = '<your_api_key_here>';

    // got websocket
    if (!PrintNode.WebSocket.isSupported()) {

        // once a websocket is authenticated you can register
        function authenticated (authData) {
            if (authData.error) {
                // most likely not authenticated, see authData.error for more detail
                return;
            }
            // authData will contain information about accountId, permissions, and maxSubscriptions

            // ok, now make some requests to the server to get data you're interested in
            // pass in optional second argument to have this called when server publishes a event
            // but you can also use the event emitter
            this.getScales({}, function (measurement) {
                // this is only meaningful if the websocket is running on the same machine
                // as the running PrintNode client
                console.log("scales data by subscription callback", measurement);
                console.log("scales latency %dms", measurement.getLatency());
            });

        }

        // error callback fired if anything goes wrong including
        //  - exceptions thrown by subscription callbacks
        //  - network issues which cause socket to fail or any timeouts
        //  - errors in printnode server or client libs
        function errorCallback (err, data) {
            console.log("Error!", err, data);
        }

        // instantiate a new
        var ws = new PrintNode.WebSocket(
            {apiKey: API_KEY},
            authenticated,
            errorCallback
        );

        // subscribe to all computer events
        ws.subscribe("computer", function computerEvent (something, info) {
            // lots of things could come in on this event
            // for now we're only interested in scalesMeasurements
            if (something instanceof PrintNode.ScalesMeasurement) {
                console.log("scales data by computer subscription", something);
            }
        });

        // subscribe to all scales events
        ws.subscribe("scales", function computerEvent (measurement) {
            console.log("scales data by scales subscription", measurement);
        });

        // debugging
        ws.subscribe('system.state', function stateChange (newState) {
            console.log("newState", newState);
        });

    // TODO fallback to polling
    } else {

        var httpOptions = {
            success: function (responseBody, repsonse) {
                console.log("success", response);
            },
            error: function (responseBody, repsonse) {
                console.log(response);
            },
            complete: function (response) {
                console.log(
                    "%d %s %s returned %db in %dms",
                    response.xhr.status,
                    response.reqMethod,
                    response.reqUrl,
                    response.xhr.responseText.length,
                    response.getDuration()
                );
            },
            timeout: function (url, duration) {
                console.log("%s timeout %d", url, duration);
            }
        };

        var http = new PrintNode.HTTP(
            new PrintNode.HTTP.ApiKey(API_KEY),
            httpOptions
        );

        http.scales(
            {success: function (response) {
                console.log("success from callback", response);
            }},
            {computerId: 0}
        ).then(
            function (response, info ) {
                console.log("success from promise", response);
            },
            function (err) {
                throw "simulated exception in a promise callback";
            }
        // If your promise callbacks start throw[ing] you can 'catch' this in the returned
        // promise from .then() but this is getting pretty meta right here.
        // Callbacks really shouldn't throw exceptions in async code like this.
        ).then(null, console.log.bind(console, "promise callbacks threw error;"));

    }

    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that there are typos in the example code.

Find and replace "repsonse" by "response" in the websocket example

Additionally, in the HTTP client example the function to print should be

```
api.createPrintjob(options, printJobPayload)
```

and not

```
api.printjob ...
```

Comment: I know its very late to reply on this post. It didn't work even after I correct the typos. PrintNode.js is not very useful to me as per my requirement,so I am not using it anymore.
But I want to leave an important comment here that can be useful for other users. All such JS printing approaches took the file to their server and then send command to the client printer for printing may be via some print Bridge like any desktop application, so these consumes lots of time. Think about printing 5000 files at once, then just imagine the delay time.

Comment: I want to add to @AbhishekSharma comment above, and say that PrintNode DOES have a setting for local pulling.
If you give them an HTTP URL instead of the file to print, the local print client will fetch the file directly to the machine while printing. It increases speed a bit, if you are doing larger files.

It only works if you already have the files generated on your server though, if you are making labels/PDFs in the browser, you have to upload them externally for the print client to fetch them. You can't send them over localhost.